# Ember redirect rule .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ember.js, url-rewriting

I'm new to ember. I have a fairly stupid question.

My site works great on `locahost:4200`, but I can't figure out how to have it display at my domain's url.

What I've done:

I created an `.htaccess` in app/public. The file contains the following:

```
Options FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

I then build the app using `ember build --env production`. The htaccess file gets added to the `app/dist` directory.

I push the code. When I go to my domain, I don't see my site.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this have to do with your hosting company and your DNS configuration in the "A" record for your service?  I'm by no means an expert at this.  I use Digital Ocean and have referenced their DNS guide in the past when dealing with such an issue:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean

Good luck, Jeff